# Access to object keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json that is something like this:

```
user = 
    {
       "info": {
                 "id": "....",
                  ......
       },
       ......
     }
```

So.. i can get the id using `user.info.id` but i need a function that can give me a property of an object using something like `getInfo(user, "info.id")` i already tried my luck with `user["info.id"]`.
Has JavaScript already got something like this? Or, how can i implement this?

BTW, I'm using node.js :)

Comment: You can access properties using `[]` syntax: `user["info"]["id"]`. So just implement a function that will transform your input into valid JS

Comment: Well.. how can i go about it? I can have more then only one "." or .. even none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to create such function.

```js
var user = {
  "info": {
    "id": 3,
  },
}

function getInfo(data, key) {
  return key.split('.').reduce(function(r, e) {
    return r[e]
  }, data)
}

console.log(getInfo(user, "info.id"))
```

With ES6 arrow function

```
function getInfo(data, key) {
  return key.split('.').reduce((r, e) => r[e] , data)
}
```